# LINQ count in same table

Tags: entity-framework, linq, code-first

I have this class in my code-first entity framework context as follows-

```
class User
{
   int UserId;
   string Name;;
   int ParentId;
}
```

Database table:

```
  UserId    Name  ParentId
   1         abc     0
   3         pqr     1
   4         xyz     1
```

I would like to select from above data like as -

```
 UserId     Name   ChildQuantity
   1         abc        2
   3         pqr        0
   4         xyz        0
```

Can I do it using LINQ or Lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join table to itself (you need a group join here):

```
from u in db.Users
join c in db.Users on u.UserId equals c.ParentId into children
select new
{
    u.UserId,
    u.Name,
    ChildQuantity = children.Count()
};
```

---

Or you can setup a navigation property for the collection of children in the user class. With this navigation property query will look like:

```
   from u in db.Users
   select new {
      u.UserId,
      u.Name,
      ChildQuantity = u.Children.Count()
   };
```

I believe it's a little bit cleaner. All you need to do - add an association property for children:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public int? ParentId { get; set; } // Note: this property is not required
    public IList<User> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And provide mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Children)
    .WithOptional().HasForeignKey(u => u.ParentId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And generated query will look like:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId],
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
    (SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[ParentId]) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: @Servey, I tried navigation property approach. But it gives exception - "System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll". Any help?

Comment: @s.k.paul option with `join` works without any problems?

Comment: join works fine. I just tried the other option "association property" you suggested. Here is the error details - 

"
UserDetail_Children_Source_UserDetail_Children_Target: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'ParentId' on entity 'UserDetail' does not match the type of property 'UserId' on entity 'UserDetail' in the referential constraint 'UserDetail_Children'."

Comment: @s.k.paul did you use exactly same settings as in answer - `int?` for parent id, `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`?

Comment: UserId is long. But mistakenly I declared ParentId as int. After correcting, now everything is okay.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
var ans = from p in src select new { p.UserID, p.Name, ChildQuantity = src.Where(c => c.ParentId == p.UserID).Count() };
```

Comment: Sounds good. Will it work actually? Let me check. Anyway, thanks for the idea.

Comment: its working. But Sergey Berezovskiy's answer is more descriptive.